# How can the threshold variant of linear programming be used to approximate the optimal solution?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

Here's a formulation of the canonical linear programming problem:

> $$
> \max_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}\right)
> \quad\text{subject to}\quad
> \mathbf{Ax\leq b}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \mathbf{x\geq 0}
> $$

One can then consider the threshold variant

> Given $t$ does there exist a $\mathbf{x}$ such that
>   $$
> t \leq \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \mathbf{Ax\leq b}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \mathbf{x\geq 0}\,?
> $$
>   (Answering this question just gives a yes-or-no answer, not an actual $\mathbf{x}$ which satisfies these properties.)

Suppose this second question can be answered in polynomial time. Can $\mathbf{x}_\text{opt}$ then be approximated (each of its entries bounded by an interval of width $2^{-n}$) in polynomial time?
To start with, as long as I can ensure that $\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}_\text{opt} \leq 2^{\text{poly}(n)}$, where $n$ is the total number of bits required to describe the input, then I could narrow down $\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}_\text{opt}$ to an interval of width $2^{-n}$ using binary search together with a polynomial number of calls to the threshold version.
However, I don't see how to actually box in $\mathbf{x}_\text{opt}$ itself using these methods.

Comment: You can first find the optimal $t$ to a certain precision, then add $t \leq c^T x$, to $Ax \leq b$, then start boxing $x$ via the objective.

Comment: This doesn't box the optimum, it boxes some arbitrary point in the remaining feasible set.

Comment: You can add $c^T x \geq b^T y$, $A^T y \leq c$, $y \geq 0$ to the set of inequalities and then start boxing $x$.

Comment: I'm confused. Are both $x$ and $y$ unknowns in this setup?

Comment: Yes, so the $x$ in your yellow block becomes the original $x$ stacked on top of $y$. The idea is based on strong duality.